# Finding mode in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below query which returns me the mode which is the most repeated value in a data set

```
select top 1 TargetPriceRec as mode 
from PricingRecurring  
Group By TargetPriceRec order by Count(*) desc
```

I get the most repeated value from this but the issue is that if there is no repeated value I am still getting the highest value in the dataset. How can I get an empty value if there are no repeating values in the dataset and also if there are multiple repeating values I still get an empty value since there is no single mode.

Any help is much appreaciated.

Thanks

Comment: Care to provide some sample data and the expected results? Your description is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`HAVING` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT TOP 1 TargetPriceRec as mode 
FROM PricingRecurring   
GROUP BY TargetPriceRec  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` for that purpose.

but you need To calculate first how many "count there are

> ```
> CREATE tABLE PricingRecurring (TargetPriceRec INT)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO PricingRecurring VALUES (10),(11),(12),(13),(13),(14),(14),(15),(15),(15)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  TOP 1 CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN  STRING_AGG(TargetPriceRec,'.') ELSE NULL END AS mode
> FROM(
> select  TargetPriceRec ,Count(*) count1
> from PricingRecurring  
> Group By TargetPriceRec) t2
> GROUP BY count1 order by count1 desc
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | mode |
> | :--- |
> | 15   |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE PricingRecurring2 (TargetPriceRec INT)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO PricingRecurring2 VALUES (10),(11),(12),(13),(13),(14),(14),(15),(15)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 9 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  TOP 1 CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN  STRING_AGG(TargetPriceRec,'.') ELSE NULL END AS mode
> FROM(
> select  TargetPriceRec ,Count(*) count1
> from PricingRecurring2  
> Group By TargetPriceRec) t2
> GROUP BY count1 order by count1 desc
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | mode |
> | :--- |
> | null |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72de2f456b1fd143e63431a4b630fd31)*